# Fetch ringtone profile from phone

Tags: android

Is it possible to fetch all the ringtones from the phone and show it into a spinner in android ? Is it possible through content provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this example [Using SimpleCursorAdapter to Display Ringtones from RingtoneManager in Android Using ListView Templates](http://learn-it-stuff.blogspot.in/2011/12/using-simplecursoradapter-to-display.html) for getting all the existing ringtones using [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html).

Comment: yeah, its showing me the right idea. Thanks a lot Imran. You are a saviour today :)

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the ability to let the user pick a ringtone from the system:

The other answer needs a lot of code and work to get going. It's way easier to use the `RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER` intent instead. This launches a dialog with a spinner, containing all the ringtones and asks the user to pick one. Example code:

```
public static final int REQUESTCODE_PICKRINGTONE = 1;

public void launchPickRingtoneIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE_PICKRINGTONE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUESTCODE_PICKRINGTONE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data
                  .getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

        if (uri != null) {
            // uri contains the URI of the selected ringtone
        } else {
            // user picked "silent" as the ringtone
        }
    }
}
```

This intent can be customized with a few [options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER), e.g. you can hide the silent option and so on. This code example here uses a custom title. Other options are used in a similar way.

Comment: @alxtsc he is asking for get all ringtones in a list not for launching default ringtone chooser

Comment: @imrankhan Where did he say that? He said "show all ringtones in a spinner", which is clearly given here. Also I'm aware that this question has an accepted answer, this post is for search engine users. They might not be aware of that possibility and it may actually be helpful for them. And it helps in case the link in your answer goes down. Otherwise this question will become completely useless for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks a lot alextsc, its exactly what i needed. Thanks for concern.

Comment: Its ok guys. Both the answers are enough to show some light on my solution. Rest i will modify according to my need. 
By the way, its "She" not "He" :)
Thanks for concern.

Comment: @JasmeetKaurChauhan Oh sorry, I didn't mean to offend you. I'm just not used to persian(?) names, so I wasn't aware that you are female. And glad we could help. :)